# Does jsoniter-scala have an equivalent to jsoniter's `Any`?

Tags: json, scala, jsonparser

Does [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) have an equivalent to (Java) jsoniter's `Any`? I'm talking about the facility described [here](https://jsoniter.com/java-features.html#lazy-is-an-option). There is no `Any` in jsoniter-scala, and I can't find an equivalent in the jsoniter-scala docs, though obviously I may have missed it.

I've tried writing my own custom type and codecs, but it's become a bit of a rabbit hole for me. Even if I get it working and write all the new tests, I won't get the efficiency (e.g., lazy evaluation) of something authored by someone who knows the library on more than just a cursory level (like me).

For reference, I am trying to intake and then later output schemaless JSON, perhaps with some checks for field values, if present.

Note that I am already familiar with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69806108/538222), but it deals with `Map[String, String]` and not `Map[String, Any]`, which is what I really need, in a production quality form.

Comment: I think the closest you can get is https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/tree/master/jsoniter-scala-circe to decode into Circe's JSON - Jsoniter want you to force deserialization into the specific target representation, with no intermediate layer which would impose an overhead. It makes it harder in cases when you'd like to just modify the raw JSON or merely pass it around. Circe's JSON is the only supported "generic" JSON representation that I am aware of.

Comment: As an option you can use more efficient approach by extraction of unparsed JSON values and then re-parsing of them for validation on demand like [here](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/commit/1cb74b7ab16e2a74127ef4a71e5af9243f79bf9c)

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok this sounded promising, but unfortunately I get an error when calling the jsoniter-scala codec macro: `'fields' parameter of 'io.circe.JsonObject.MapAndVectorJsonObject' should be defined as 'val' or 'var' in the primary constructor`. (This is after first specifying `.withAllowRecursiveTypes(true)`.)